# mod_rewrite confusion

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a few rewritten urls pointing to the original dynamic urls like so:

```
http://mysite.com/profile/edit/ => http://mysite.com/index.php?action=profile&sa=edit
```

Here's the rewriterule in the htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?action=$1&sa=$2 [L]
```

^ So that works just fine.

Now I also have the following url:

```
http://mysite.com/search/editorials/ => http://mysite.com/index.php?action=search&category=editorials
```

The rewrite which follows the previous rewrite rule posted above:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?action=$1&category=$2 [L]
```

^ This does not work. I checked the $_SERVER array and this is what's being redirected to the query string:

```
action=search&sa=editorials
```

I've been at this for a day so far, I've tried various tutorials but with no luck. How do I get this to work?

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two rewrites are conflicting with each other. You need to create some type of distinction between the two of them

RewriteRule ^**account**/(.*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?action=$1&sa=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?action=$1&category=$2 [L]

**or** make the parameters consistent and use a single rewrite:

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?action=$1&**parm1**=$2 [L]